# Curl correios rastreamento

Tags: php, web-service, libcurl

Estou tentando fazer um *POST* com curl para verificar minhas entregas. Porém não está retornando nada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<?php    
$post = array('Objetos' => 'PN752805878BR');

// iniciar CURL
$ch = curl_init();
// informar URL e outras funções ao CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
// Acessar a URL e retornar a saída
$output = curl_exec($ch);
// liberar
curl_close($ch);
// Imprimir a saída
echo $output;    
?>
```

Comment: http://sooho.com.br/2017/03/24/rastreamento-de-pedidos-correios-php-soap/

Answer (score 2):

Esse curl foi feito para não funcionar, na verdade os problemas:

1. Sua chamada está para a página errada, `/sistemas/rastreamento`, ao acessar a página pelo navegador e "rastrear" alguma encomenda, você faz uma requisição para outra página, `/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado.cfm?`.

   Essa segunda é a página correta, ao menos é quem foi feita para receber os dados do formulário.
2. O website exige que envie um `Referer` e seria ideal, *embora não necessário*, definir um User-Agent.

---

Isso já seria suficiente:

```
$post = ['objetos' => 'PN752805878BR', 'btnPesq' => 'Buscar'];

$ch = curl_init('http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado.cfm?');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

echo $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Se não quiser usar o `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` e o `CURLOPT_REFERER` você pode usar diretamente o `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, que pessoalmente prefiro. Adicionando outras correções, como limitação de protocolos e suporte para compressão de dados poderia usar:

```
$post = ['objetos' => 'PN752805878BR', 'btnPesq' => 'Buscar'];

$ch = curl_init('http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado.cfm?');

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Referer: http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
    ],
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS
]);

echo $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Depois de testar remova o `echo` para não mostrar o resultado na página, e use o `$output` como quiser. De qualquer uma das duas formas isso não é totalmente seguro, o site que está se conectando não suporta HTTPS, o que expõe a vários problemas.

Comment: O segundo funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado, se eu quiser colocar o codigo de produto na URL, ele funcionaria também, Existe algum modo de fazer isso?

Comment: Não entendi em que URL deseja colocar. Se deseja obter uma informação da sua URL basta usar `$_GET['nome_da_variavel']` e então poderá definir `$post['objetos'] = $_GET['nome_da_variavel']`. Agora se sua questão é o cURL, você deseja conectar nos Correios usando o parametro no URL, ao invés de no corpo, acredito que isso não é possível, ao menos acredito que não irá funcionar.  São duas questões distintas.